# Incorrect implementation of the <seealso> xml tag

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to use the seealso tag as follows:

```
/// <seealso cref="Thorlabs::MotionControl::DeviceManagerCLI::DeviceSettings">DeviceSettings</seealso>
```

What I want is a link to the referenced class but without the namespaces in the text. However, Doxygen generates the following:

[image]

Comment: I think this is an incorrect implementation in doxygen. Can you submit a problem report in bugzilla?

Answer (score 0):

I always use [\sa ...](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsa)

e.g.

```
/// \sa DeviceSettings
```